# Suggested off topic choice: Overly narrow

Tags: feature-request

On our off-topic list we have a 'too broad' option.

Would it make sense to also have a 'too narrow' option? I'm thinking along the lines of this question:

[Should I keep a 1:1 scale for a vehicle wrap vinyl print made in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26347/what-dimensions-do-i-use-for-a-vinyl-print-4m-x-1-3m)

The answer to that question is really only useful to that particular user and that particular project.

Even more specific, perhaps we need to have a 'off topic because you need to ask your vendor/printer/service provider' as these types of questions to crop up with some frequency.

Answer (score 2):

My first concern with this is that it goes directly against the [closing changes recently implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/216955):

> #### 5(A). "Too Localized" is no longer necessary since the specific off-topic reasons now address its main use case. (new)
>
> Too Localized was, by far, the most misused close reason in our
>   surveys, with both Community Managers and Moderators deeming over 50%
>   of randomly sampled TL closures to not have merited closure (including
>   on SO).
>
> Today, TL is used helpfully on code dump questions on SO, but the new
>   OT reasons are where this is now correctly addressed. SO can use
>   "Large blocks of code with requests for debugging without meaningful
>   supporting info" as a specific OT reason.

As you can see from the discussion below the post, there is a lot of disagreement with this removal.

My second concern is that we've already used our 3 allotted custom close reasons, and I think all three of them serve the site well. We can request that the community team provide us with the capability to have a fourth, but we must prove to them that it is something this site absolutely needs. Trying to make a convincing argument for a "too localized" close reason might not go over well seeing as it goes against the recent change dictated by the Stack Exchange team.

In general, I don't really have a problem with localized questions. Robert Cartaino [put it nicely](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-are-legal-questions-on-topic/601#comment2548_601) over at Pets.SE meta:

> I don't particularly agree with your premise about local questions.
>   When someone searches dog licenses in Los Angeles, I sure would like
>   them to find ***this*** site. Once we ask allllll those questions that have
>   been asked hundreds of times on every other site on this subject, it's
>   those long-tailed questions that only a few people can answer — and ***do***
>   answer — that will really make this site shine. It's the interesting
>   rarely-asked, well-answered question that will make this site stand
>   out in the long term. This site should strive to become The Complete
>   Compendium™ of all things pets.

Regarding the question you linked, I can see where we can make improvement but I don't think it's so terrible that we should banish it from the site.

Comment: So it sounds to adhere to the 'TL is deprecated' we maybe need to ask for and create our own custom OT option more centric to graphic design?

Comment: As for the example, I don't know if I agree that it's the same context. That is 'localized' in that it's about a region...rather than one individual's unique issue. There's lots of people in LA who may need dog licenses. There's only one person working with one vendor on one particular project.

Comment: Oh, finally...I don't think we need to 'ban' it either. It's just that it's a question with a stock answer: Ask your vendor for the spec's. At the very least, I suppose we should find the one answer that succinctly explains the 'ask your vendor' that we can redirect and then mark as 'duplicate'.

Comment: @DA01 Maybe we can redirect to this question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26353/proper-resolution-for-a-large-banner?noredirect=1

Comment: @Yisela I actually just wrote a new community wiki answer from scratch that we can maybe use: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should would love feedback/contribution from others.

Comment: @DA01 great idea!

Comment: @DA01 Perfect! I just changed the link to yours. Nice job!!

Answer (score 0):

With such a narrowly focused issue, I'd explain why such a decision is made. Don't give an answer for the moment, explain why you might need to make said decision in the future. And there's a ton of good stuff in such that would be useful for other people in the future.